# Manipulating downloaded file name?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am wondering if there is a way to intercept files being downloaded from Chrome and rename them before they are saved in the downloads folder. If this is possible, can the download location be altered? Thanks!

Comment: [`chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#event-onDeterminingFilename)

Comment: Holy smokes how did I miss that there was an actual API for this. Thanks!!